# GUI Button Highlight

Tags: touchscreen, gui, tkinter

I'm having an issue with the highlight of the buttons on a GUI that I created with tkinter.

When I run the GUI on my windows machine and the cursor is over the button, the button is not highlighted and will highlight on a button press only.  This is what I am wanting.

When I run the GUI on the PI (Raspbian) the button will highlight when the cursor is on the button and will stay highlighted until the cursor is moved off of the button.  This becomes a problem when using a touchscreen for a display.

Is there a way to fix this so the button will highlight on a press only?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be on Stack Overflow

Comment: I had the same issue with tkinter (check)buttons on a 7" touchscreen. Searched the internet and found this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4vkzuu/remove_mouse_hover_from_tkinter_ubuntu/ It was the key to solve my issue.
Maybe it can help you out?